# Python sublists - List Index out of range

Tags: python, list, while-loop, range, global

**Hey Community,**
I have a problem which I cant seem to solve.
Basically I use an Global List and want to access certain indexes in a while loop
Here is my setup:

```
PossibleJumps = [
[[1,2],1,[2,4]],
[[3,4],1,[2,3]],
[[2,5],1,[1,1]],
[[1,3],0,[1,5]],
[[4,5],0,[1,4]],
[[6,6],0,[1,2]]]
```

and the function that gets called to perform the action:

```
def buildPJsphere(level, box):
I = 1
while len(PossibleJumps) * 4 > I:
    CurrentJumps = PossibleJumps[I-1]
    CurrentJumpRL = CurrentJumps[0]
    CurrentJumpHD = CurrentJumps[1]
    CurrentJumpFB = CurrentJumps[2]

             .......

    I += 1
```

If I run the code I get the Message "IndexError: list index out of range"
in Line 4 of the second code.

> CurrentJumps = PossibleJumps[I-1]

I appreciate all of your help -
Thanks in advance,
Marco

Comment: Did you try changing I to equal zero to start with. Therefore you could write: `I = 0` and then in the while loop `CurrentJumps = PossibleJumps[I]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while condition is failing. You're basically saying continue while `i` is less than four times the length of `PossibleJumps`. Which, by definition, is bigger than the size of `PossibleJumps`. Thus when `I` get's too big, it goes beyond the bounds of the array.

By the way you are using `PossibleJumps`, you only need to worry about the outer size, i.e. change your while condition to

```
while I < len( PossibleJumps ):
    CurrentJumps = PossibleJumps[I-1]
    ...
```

That should fix your problem, and still give you access to all the sub lists.

A a side note, using `print` is useful for tracking down bugs. In this, since it's not working right, you could have tried

```
print I
print PossibleJumps[ I ]
```

right above the line that failed. Then you can see that the index was getting too big, and the `print PossibleJumps[ I ]` line would have failed, showing you that you can't use that big of a value to reference the array.

Comment: Ok now I found the problem it was just my brain messing it up :D because initially I wanted to cycle it through 4 times but that's obviously the wrong way.

Comment: To loop it four identical times, simply wrap what you need in an outer for loop.

Comment: Can you accept as answer, to get it out of the 'unanswered' lists?